# How do I get the value from a button into a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function where it creates a button with a certain value. In my html form I have a checkbox. I want the value from the buttons to be added in the checkbox. For some reason I am not able to figure it out..

```js
var showDate = new Date();
        var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        var theForm = '<form class="" action="insert.php" method="post"><input id="day"type="checkbox" name="day" value=""><br><input id="btn" type="submit"  value="Send"></form>';

        function drawTable(forDate) {
          var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
          var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
          var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          var xy = document.getElementById("x");
          xy.innerHTML = "";
          for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            xy.appendChild(newRow);
            for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
              var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);
              var textarea = document.createElement("button");
              textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
              textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
              newRow.appendChild(textarea);
              textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
              textarea.setAttribute("id", "day");
              textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 );
              textarea.setAttribute("value", newdate + "-" + day1);
              textarea.innerHTML = day1; 
              var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
              textarea1.setAttribute("class", "content");
              newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
              textarea1.innerHTML = theForm;
              cellsToDraw--;
            }
          }
          var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            var active = checkIfAnyVisible();
            if (active) {
              active.className = 'content';
              active.style.maxHeight = null;
            }
            if (content.style.maxHeight){
              content.style.maxHeight = null;
              content.className = 'content';
            } else if (!checkIfAnyVisible()) {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            content.style.width = "100%";
            content.className = 'content active';
            }
          });
        }
        function checkIfAnyVisible() {
          for (var i=0; i<acc.length; i++) {
            if (acc[i].nextElementSibling.className.includes('active')) {
              return acc[i].nextElementSibling;
            } else {
              continue;
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
    
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()] + " " + showDate.getFullYear();
        drawTable(showDate);
      };

        function daysInMonth(month, year) {
          var days;
          switch (month) {
            case 1: 
            var leapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
            days = leapYear ? 29 : 28;
            break;
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            days = 30;
            break;
            default:
            days = 31;
          }
          return days;
        }
```

```css
    .row {
          transition: 0.4s;
          
        }
     
        .content {
          max-height: 0;
          transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 98.3%;
        }
        #x{
          width: 75%;
        }
   
      #displayingMonth {
      }
```

```html
      <h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1><br>
      <div id="x" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a value to a checkbox, you can use the simple `.value = myvalue`.

Instead of this:
 `textarea.setAttribute("value", newdate + "-" + day1);` 
Use this:
`textarea.value = newdate + "-" + day1`

but first, make sure that your variable `textarea` is beign correctly selected. 
I don't know if you are using jQuery, but with pure JS, you will select your checkbox with: 
`document.getElementById('day')`

**EDIT**
you had a bad mistake with the `ids`, the way you were doing you were setting the same ID to many elements, what is wrong, IDs must be unique!
So i adjusted this.

The code: (**look for comments inside the JS code**)

```js
var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var theForm = '<form class="" action="insert.php" method="post"><input type="checkbox" name="day" value=""><br><input id="btn" type="submit" value="Send"></form>';

function drawTable(forDate) {
  var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
  var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
  var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  var xy = document.getElementById("x");
  xy.innerHTML = "";
  for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    xy.appendChild(newRow);
    for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {

      //new function to get day
      var day1 = getCorrectDay(c);
      var textarea = document.createElement("button");
      textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
      textarea.setAttribute("class", "row");
      newRow.appendChild(textarea);
      textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");

      //textarea.setAttribute("id", "day"); --> REMOVE THIS, ID must be unique
     
 textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 );
      textarea.value = newdate + "-" + day1;
      textarea.innerHTML = day1; 
      var textarea1 = document.createElement("div");
      textarea1.setAttribute("class", "content");
      newRow.appendChild(textarea1);
      textarea1.innerHTML = theForm;

      //Lets find the checkbox
      var myCheckbox = textarea1.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      myCheckbox.value = newdate + "-" + day1; //setting the value
      console.log(myCheckbox); //Logging to see if value is there

      cellsToDraw--;
    }
  }
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    var active = checkIfAnyVisible();
    if (active) {
      active.className = 'content';
      active.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
      content.className = 'content';
    } else if (!checkIfAnyVisible()) {
    content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    content.style.width = "100%";
    content.className = 'content active';
    }
  });
}
function checkIfAnyVisible() {
  for (var i=0; i<acc.length; i++) {
    if (acc[i].nextElementSibling.className.includes('active')) {
      return acc[i].nextElementSibling;
    } else {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

}

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()] + " " + showDate.getFullYear();
drawTable(showDate);
};

function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  var days;
  switch (month) {
    case 1: 
    var leapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
    days = leapYear ? 29 : 28;
    break;
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    days = 30;
    break;
    default:
    days = 31;
  }
  return days;
}


//Created a class to get the day based on each loop iteration
function getCorrectDay(idx){
  var day = (idx + 1).toString();
  if (day.length < 2){
    day = '0' + day;
  }
  return day;
}
```

```css
.row {
      transition: 0.4s;

    }

    .content {
      max-height: 0;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 98.3%;
    }
    #x{
      width: 75%;
    }

  #displayingMonth {
  }
```

```html
<h1 id="displayingMonth"></h1><br>
<div id="x" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin! But where should I write all this? And how would the checkbox get the right value? (sorry if I ask stupid questions..)

Comment: But what is the expected right value? And when do you need the value to be on the checkbox? I mean, try to add a complete example of your code where we can see the code running

Comment: So I added a comment on what the right value is. I want the value of the checkbox to be the same as where I added the comment. When I send it all in the db, I want the checkbox to have the value of where I put the comment above.

Comment: Ok, in that way, just change the part where is the comment with `textarea.value = newdate + "-" + day1;` as I said in the answer. But keep in mind that it is inside a `for`, so the value of the checkbox will be the last `newdate + "-" + day1;` that the loop iterated with.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have your entire code and I don't know what exactly is the expected output at the end because I'm not aware of your web app main goal... debug your code to see if is that what you want. All I know is that this: `textarea.value = newdate + "-" + day1`  will absolutely change the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Hi Calvin, here is a jsfiddle, this might help? https://jsfiddle.net/coc5rcaq/11/

Comment: I prefer to work here in S.O, so I'll add that fiddle into your question, ok? just accept the edit that I made

Comment: Thats fine, did you see the jsfiddle that I added? And I accepted the edit, should I do something else?

Comment: Yes, i'm working on it, now i'm a little busy, but I'll answer in a few hours

Comment: Okey, im sorry!

Comment: @JaneHansen answer edited, I think now it's everything you need